# Which is efficient way to bifurcate List of nested object list ? java 8 flatmap vs for each?

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I've a `Terminal` object:

```
class Terminal{

    List<TerminalPeriodApplicability> periods= new ArrayList<>();
    //few other attributes

    //getters & setters

}
```

`TerminalPeriodApplicability` object:

```
class TerminalPeriodApplicability{

    String name;
    boolean isRequired;
    //getters & setters
}
```

I want to bifurcate names of `TerminalPeriodApplicability` into `optional` & `mandatory` `Set`s based on `isRequired`'s value.

I've tried two approaches of it. One with two `forEach` and the other with `flatMap`.

```
List<Terminal> terminals= getTerminals();
Set<String> mandatoryPeriods = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> optionalPeriods = new HashSet<>();
```

**Approach 1**:

```
terminals.forEach(terminal -> terminal.getApplicablePeriods().forEach(period->{
    if(period.getIsRequired())
        mandatoryPeriods.add(period.name());
    else
        optionalPeriods.add(period.name());
}));
```

**Approach 2:**

```
List<TerminalPeriodApplicability> applicablePeriods = terminals
                .stream()
                .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getApplicablePeriods().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

applicablePeriods.forEach(period->{
    if(period.getIsRequired())
        mandatoryPeriods.add(period.name());
    else
        optionalPeriods.add(period.name());
});
```

I would like to know which approach is more efficient in terms of time & space complexity. Or is there any better solution to solve this problem?

Comment: The `forEach` approach can be simplified to `terminals.forEach(terminal -> terminal.getApplicablePeriods().forEach(period -> (period.getIsRequired()? mandatoryPeriods: optionalPeriods).add(period.name()) ));`, still, the Stream approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56001986/2711488) looks cleaner…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a different terminal operation in your `flatMap` version - `partitioningBy` instead of `toList` - and avoid the second `forEach`:

```
Map<Boolean,List<TerminalPeriodApplicability>> periods = terminals
            .stream()
            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getApplicablePeriods().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(TerminalPeriodApplicability::getIsRequired);
```

or

```
Map<Boolean,Set<TerminalPeriodApplicability>> periods = terminals
            .stream()
            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getApplicablePeriods().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(TerminalPeriodApplicability::getIsRequired,
                                               Collectors.toSet());
```

Correction: Since you want the two `Set`s to contain `String`s instead of `TerminalPeriodApplicability` instances, it should be:

```
Map<Boolean,Set<String>> periods = terminals
            .stream()
            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getApplicablePeriods().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(TerminalPeriodApplicability::getIsRequired,
                                               Collectors.mapping(TerminalPeriodApplicability::name,
                                                                  Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: correct answer is this `Map<Boolean,Set<String>> periods = terminals
            .stream()
            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getApplicablePeriods().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(TerminalPeriodApplicability::getIsRequired,Collectore.mapping(TerminalPeriodApplicability::getName,Collectors.toSet()));`

Comment: @HadiJ Oh, I didn't notice OP was putting the name `String`s in the Sets. Thanks. I'll fix that.

Comment: Wow. This is great ! I was not knowing much about partitioningBy method. Thank you @Eran & HadiJ